# Very slow startup of ASP.NET applications

Tags: asp.net, jit, ngen

I have an ASP.NET applications with quite small number of pages. The problem I see is that the startup time is quite slow. As far as I can tell, most of the time is spent in JIT. Pre-compiling the applications seem not very helpful in reducing the #methods JIT as reported thru PerfMon. Does anybody know what I can do to reduce the startup time further? 
Is it true that there is no way to pre-jit an ASP.NET application using NGEN?

Answer (score 4):

Have you set the following element in your web.config?

```
<compilation debug="false"/>
```

Take a look at http://www.aspnetresources.com/articles/debug_code_in_production.aspx for some useful information on what the framework does when you have debug mode set to true: it's fairly old but a lot of it is still relevant.

Without knowing a little more about what your app does, what you've got going on in the *Application_Start* event etc, it will be difficult to give you more specific advice.

Comment: I can assure you debug is set to false and nothing is in Application_Start. In fact, as I have said, PerfMon reported a lot of time is spent in #methods JIT during application startup. I understand a possible workaround is to reduce the number of methods requiring JIT but what if it is already the minimal set? Does it mean nothing can be done?